# Frequent tab cleared for any tag

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

The "frequent" tab for *any* tag is suddenly empty.

> You are on the Frequent tab.
>   There are no frequently asked questions
>   at the moment.
>   Perhaps you'd like to select a different tab?

This is quite disastrous. Did the database have a meltdown?

In case it matters, I'm using Firefox.

EDIT:

Seems the same issue appears no matter which Stack Exchange site. Other users say they experience the same problem.

Comment: repro on Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84 m [screenshot](http://imgur.com/clLRQkp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, shoot. Just when I thought I had all the gremlins eradicated; k, thanks; I've reverted the code that caused this - all should be good again within a few minutes.

Comment: Confirmed - now working again!

Comment: That was a quick gremlin bust, thank you :)

Comment: Stop letting Gizmo get wet and the off spring eating after Midnight Marc! :)

Comment: @Lundin that's because I *basically* have a big switch here with labels "use the well-known and mostly-working stuff, even if it is slow" and "use the faster but not battle-hardened rewrite" :)

Comment: *Cough[codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)cough*.  :)

Comment: @Lundin I suspect 8 kloc (which is what "tag engine v2" weighs in at) might be a little bit above what we expect in a single question there...

Comment: @MarcGravell Just teasing :)

Comment: @Lundin the good news is: we're back on v2 now, and *nobody noticed* (so far), which probably means the remaining gremlins are playing a more tactical game...